# Use F# list as a DataSource in WinForms and / or MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, f#, c#-to-f#

Let's say that I have a very simple F# DU type, like:

```
namespace Test

    type State = 
        | DC
        | MD
        | VA
        // ...

    with 
        static member All = 
            [|
                (State.DC, "District of Columbia")
                (State.MD, "Maryland")
                (State.VA, "Virginia")
            |]
```

The static member All is just for convenience of the example and it can be twisted any way possible. The question is NOT about that.

I want to bind that array (State.All) or any suitable derivative of it to a listbox / combobox in C# WinForm so that ValueMember will be bound to the "State" (State.DC, State.MD, etc...) and DisplayMember will be bound to the "label" ("District of Columbia", "Maryland", etc...). The question is how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried doing it the same way as you would with any other datasource? What didn't work?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin If you mean: list box ==> Properties ==> DataSource ==> (downarrow) ==> Add Project Data Source ==> Object / Next ==> Choose State object, then it has only Tags under it. Binding to Tags (or State itself) results in nothing appearing on the list box. So that did not work.

Comment: Don't use visual designer. Write code.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin The question is EXACTLY!!! about that. So, if you could,  provide an example, then, please, do so.

Comment: Do you mean to say that your question is not about F# as such, but rather "how to attach winforms datasource without using visual designer"?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin If I could down vote your comments I would've. They are totally useless and irrelevant. To bind DataSource the object must have some properties, which pure DU does not have, except Tag. So the solution was to add a couple of properties, for example: member this.DisplayMember = this.ToString() member this.ValueMember = this
and then bind them in the code like:
BindingList<State> StateData = new BindingList<State>(State.AllList());
lb_State.DisplayMember = "DisplayMember";
lb_State.ValueMember = "ValueMember";
lb_State.DataSource = StateData;

Comment: Your DU doesn't have properties, but your tuples do. You were asking to bind the tuples, not the DU.